# Проблема с JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Пользуюсь библиотекой jqery-ui, и при разработке появилась проблема того, что на один draggable-элемент могут реагировать сразу 2 droppable-элемента. Мне нужно чтобы мог реагировать только один. При этом у draggable-элемента задан tolerance: 'touch'.
Схематично проблему я попытался изобразить на картинке:
[image]

Comment: Ну что, никто не поможет?

Comment: Я бы попробовал помочь, но я не могу понять процесс, который у вас происходит. Схема - это хорошо, но лично для меня, думаю, что кусок html-кода, js и объяснение того, что вы в итоге хотите получить - быстрее прояснило бы картину.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, ждать ответ на свой комментарий у меня нет сегодня времени, поэтому я наугад смодулировал ситуацию. Посмотрите [рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/nFhnD/1/) и если поможет, то плиззз ))

```
<span id="drag_el">Draggable</span>
<ul id="drop_list">
    <li>Droppable</li>
    <li>Droppable</li>
    <li>Droppable</li>
    <li>Droppable</li>
    <li>Droppable</li>
</ul>
```

-

```
#drop_list {
    width: 145px;
}
#drop_list li, #drag_el {
    padding: 15px 35px;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    margin: 2px;
}
#drag_el {
    float: right;
    background: #FF0;
}
.red {
    background: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
}
.green {
    background: #0F0;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

-

```
$('#drag_el').draggable({cursor: 'move'});
$('#drop_list li').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'green',
    drop: function() {
        $(this).addClass('red');
        $('#drop_list li').not(this).removeClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ситуация выглядит примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/nFhnD/3/. Т.к. draggable довольно длинный, у droppable задан tolerance: 'touch'. Из-за этого на droppable реагируют сразу 2 draggable.

Comment: Сударь, а зачем вам задавать этот параметр? Ведь если простыми словами, то его охарактеризовать можно, как "сработь, при соприкосновении". А если он у вас еще и по высоте будет больше? Тогда сразу три droppable-елемента будут реагировать.

Comment: А вы попробуйте без него дропнуть такой длинный элемент. Поясню: его требуется наполовину затащить в один из dropp'ов. 

*Вообще, по моему мнению должен реагировать тот из dropp'ов, в котором  dragg находится большей своей частью.*

Comment: Первое, что на ум пришло - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/nFhnD/4/

Comment: Да, я тоже рассматривал такой вариант. Но он мне также кажется не слишком удобным. Просто я хочу посмотреть, какие ещё идеи решения данной проблемы могут быть.

Comment: Если перетаскиваемый элемент больше, чем droppable, то увы, но вариантов во многих отношениях не так уж и много остается. Практически все варианты "зла" мы рассмотрели, посему выбирайте меньшее ))

Comment: Ок, так и сделаю. Спасибо за помощь.